# Fragment being displayed, overlaps current fragment instead of replacing it

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

**UPDATE:**
Still having the same problem, but I've added a fragment into the main_activity
welcome_screen_fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context="me.alexoladele.quotebook.WelcomeScreen">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_screen_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welcome_screen_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="@string/start_button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

WelcomeScreen.java:

```
package me.alexoladele.quotebook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link WelcomeScreen.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link WelcomeScreen#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class WelcomeScreen extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    //private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public WelcomeScreen() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment WelcomeScreen.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static WelcomeScreen newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        WelcomeScreen fragment = new WelcomeScreen();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_screen_fragment, container, false);
    }

   /* // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    *//**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     *//*
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }*/
}
```

**ORIGINAL:**
The setup I have is a main_activity fragment that just has welcome text, and when you tap the start button, it's supposed to switch fragments. Instead of replacing the current fragment, it just overlays it on top of the main_activity fragment and won't allow me to perform the action associated with the new fragment.

[Main Activity example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DALEU.png)

[quote_fragment overlapping main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q8HH.png)

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contextClickable="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="me.alexoladele.quotebook.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_screen_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welcome_screen_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="@string/start_button" />
</FrameLayout>
```

ActivityMain.java

```
package me.alexoladele.quotebook;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int count = 0;
    final QuoteFragment quoteFragment = new QuoteFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        final TextView welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_screen_text);
        if (startButton != null)
            startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startSecondFragment(); // start your fragment from MainActivity
                    //startButton.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                    //welcomeText.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                }
            });


    }

    // This method will be in charge of handling your second fragment
    private void startSecondFragment() {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .replace(R.id.main_activity, quoteFragment)
                .commit();



    }


}
```

quote_fragment.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/quote_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tap_screen"
        android:textColor="#a6a6a6"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/person"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/quotist_name"
        android:textColor="#585858"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

QuoteFragment.java:

```
package me.alexoladele.quotebook;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

//import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class QuoteFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_fragment,container, false);

        FrameLayout touch = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.main_activity);
        final TextView quoteText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quote);


        // Makes quotes array
        //region Description
        String[] quotes = {
                (Quotes go here, but I didnt put them here to save space)
        };
        //endregion

        // Put quotes array into arraylist
        final List<String> quoteList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(quotes));

        //
        if (touch != null)
            touch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (count >= quoteList.size()) {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    Quote q = new Quote("");
                    q.setQuote(quoteList.get(count));

                    quoteText.setText(q.getQuote());
                    count++;

                    v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_fragment, container, false);
    }




}
```

Comment: "Instead of replacing the current fragment, it just overlays it on top of the main_activity fragment" -- you only have one fragment. `activity_main` is the layout for the activity. It is not managed by a fragment.

Comment: So there isn't a fragment placed inside of it?

Comment: Not based on the code that you are showing here. There is no "automatic" fragment for an activity. Fragments only exist if you create them (or use ones from libraries). You have a `QuoteFragment`, but that's it.

Comment: @CommonsWare so should I create a new xml and .java file with a fragment, and include it from the main activity?

Comment: If you want to be able to replace your original UI with the UI from a fragment, that is one approach. You would run a `FragmentTransaction` at the outset that adds the fragment with your starting UI. Then, you can run a later `FragmentTransaction` to `replace()` that fragment with your `QuoteFragment`.

Comment: @CommonsWare the problem i get with this is that when I include the fragment and select the new layout I created, it gives me a stack overflow error. I can update this comment with the error displayed

Comment: I would recommend that you post a separate question, showing your code for that approach, along with the full stack trace of your error.

Comment: @CommonsWare nevermind, I had made the fragment wrong. Now I'm back at the original problem